Can factor neutralization hedge market risk
While coding a strategy that uses 50% of the fund to long the group of stocks with the greatest exposure to a factor called MIF, and the other 50% to short the group of stocks with the least exposure to the MIF factor, I had a conversation with my colleague about whether the above strategy can prevail in market downturn, for example, when 80% or 90% of the stocks are going down. To create a strategy that is market neutral, returns from shorts should at least be able to cover losses from long positions in market downturn
. My colleague says that after industry neutralization and size factor neutralization(size is measured by marker capitalization), the above strategy can hedge most of the downward market risk, which means returns from shorts can offset losses from long positions by making sure that industry and size factor is evenly concentrated in long and short positions. However, there are many other factors such as growth, momentum, value, etc., that are not neutralized. These factors can be heavily concentrated in long or short positions. Thus, I think any combinations of factor neutralization can never hedge downward market risk, and the only way to hedge market risk and create a market neutral strategy is to buy derivatives. Is my observation accurate? Thank you!

When you say you are market size factor neutralized, do you mean that you are neutral to market and size factors? Because there isn't such a thing called "market size" factor. Also, I think it might be better to eliminate downside risk using a dollar neutral strategy.

Thank you i edited the question. The size factor is measured by market capitalization

IMHO, it depends a lot on how you quantify the market risk. If you assume,  like French / Fama / MSCI / Barra that single stock returns are attributable to factor betas $\times$ factor returns plus some idiosyncratic returns, and if you use this methodology to calculate VaR / extended shortfall of a portfolio that's flat some betas, then you might see lower VaR / ES than a similar portfolio that's not flat those betas. But if we use the same multi-factor model in constructing a portfolio and measuring its market risk, are we missing some perspective on the risk?

I.e., do we truly lower the market risk by flattening the betas or gaming the calculation methodology somewhat? Would the risk be lower if we calculated VaR / ES, for example, using a one-factor CAPM, or a full covariance matrix correlating every pair of equities?

Thank you Dimitri I edited the question to make it more clear for you

@DimitriVulis, I'm not OP, but I really liked your explanation here. For me, flattening the beta works better when you have the least idiosyncratic returns or minimal alpha (best fitting model). In that sense, hedging market risk would be equivalent to neutralizing all the factors exposures.
